# perl Padre IDE standard input not working

Tags: perl, stdin, padre

I'm using padre 0.64 as perl IDE on windows vista  The standard input command is not working , I tried the same code on the cmd line and it did work i.e

```
 my $k = <>;
 print $k;
```

Is there a way to fix it ?

Comment: Is it just the diamond operator or doesn't `<STDIN>` work either?

Comment: @flesk <STDIN> not working too

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's quite an old version of Padre. The internal output window is that, just an output window.
You need to turn on the "Use external window for execution" (checking the box).
In 0.91 it is in Tools -> Preferences -> Language Perl 5 but it was somewhere else in 0.64.

It used to be in "Tools -> Preferences -> Run Parameters"

Comment: Workaround successfully tested for Padre 1.00 on Ubuntu 14.4